# Create a table to have only working days excluding weekends and public holidays

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

1st of them consists of working days for each month (year = 2020):

| Month | Date from | Date to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 01/01/2020 | 31/01/2020 |
| February | 01/02/2020 | 29/02/2020 |
| March | 01/03/2020 | 31/03/2020 |

2nd of them has a dates with public holidays for 2020 with the following format:

| Date | Week day | Code | Working hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | Wednesday | Holiday | 0 |
| 08/03/2020 | Sunday | Holiday | 0 |
| 01/09/2020 | Tuesday | Holiday | 0 |
| 24/12/2020 | Thursday | Holiday | 0 |

I would like to create 1 table (with the format of 2nd table) which has data only working days excluding public holidays from 2nd table and weekends from calendar for 2020.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean "It should be done using PL/SQL."? PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language. If you want to create a table then that is just an SQL query and is not PL/SQL.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be SQL query

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE working_days (
  day           DATE PRIMARY KEY,
  week_day      VARCHAR2(9)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(day, 'FMDay')) AS VARCHAR2(9))),
  code          VARCHAR2(20),
  working_hours NUMBER(4,2)
);
```

Then insert data using:

```sql
INSERT INTO working_days (day, code, working_hours)
WITH days (dt, date_to) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(date_from),
         date_to
  FROM   working_day_ranges
UNION ALL
  SELECT dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         date_to
  FROM   days
  WHERE  dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY <= date_to
)
SELECT dt, 'Working Day', 23
FROM   days d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (             -- Not a holiday
         SELECT 1
         FROM   holidays h
         WHERE  d.dt = h.dt
       )
AND    dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW') < 5 -- Not a Saturday or Sunday;
ORDER BY dt;
```

*(Alter the expected working hours, etc. as suits you.)*

Which, assuming your tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE working_day_ranges (Date_from, Date_to) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', DATE '2020-02-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-01', DATE '2020-03-31' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE working_day_ranges
  ADD month VARCHAR2(8)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(date_from, 'FMMonth')) AS VARCHAR2(8)));

CREATE TABLE holidays (dt, Code, Working_hours) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Holiday', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-08', 'Holiday', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-09-01', 'Holiday', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-24', 'Holiday', 0 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE holidays
  ADD week_day VARCHAR2(9)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(dt, 'FMDay')) AS VARCHAR2(9)));
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM working_days;
```

Outputs:

> | DAY | WEEK_DAY | CODE | WORKING_HOURS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 02-JAN-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 03-JAN-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 06-JAN-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 07-JAN-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 08-JAN-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 09-JAN-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 10-JAN-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 13-JAN-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 14-JAN-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 15-JAN-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 16-JAN-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 17-JAN-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 20-JAN-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 21-JAN-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 22-JAN-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 23-JAN-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 24-JAN-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 27-JAN-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 28-JAN-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 29-JAN-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 30-JAN-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 31-JAN-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 03-FEB-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 04-FEB-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 05-FEB-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 06-FEB-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 07-FEB-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 10-FEB-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 11-FEB-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 12-FEB-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 13-FEB-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 14-FEB-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 17-FEB-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 18-FEB-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 19-FEB-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 20-FEB-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 21-FEB-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 24-FEB-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 25-FEB-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 26-FEB-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 27-FEB-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 28-FEB-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 02-MAR-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 03-MAR-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 04-MAR-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 05-MAR-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 06-MAR-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 09-MAR-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 10-MAR-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 11-MAR-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 12-MAR-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 13-MAR-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 16-MAR-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 17-MAR-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 18-MAR-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 19-MAR-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 20-MAR-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 23-MAR-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 24-MAR-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 25-MAR-20 | Wednesday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 26-MAR-20 | Thursday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 27-MAR-20 | Friday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 30-MAR-20 | Monday | Working Day | 23 |
> | 31-MAR-20 | Tuesday | Working Day | 23 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f43c70cb21ae818070c94540b76c7ad3)*

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working as expected